# how to use onRedirectCallback in Auth0 react sdk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, auth0

due to onRedirecrCallback I always get isAuthencated false on my redirect URI page.I don't know how to resolve this issue.

```
const onRedirectCallback = (appState:any) => {
  Navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Auth0Provider domain={domain} clientId={clientId} redirectUri={`${window.location.origin}/review`}  audience="unique identifier">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Auth0Provider> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, appState has its own TS type and it is **AppState**.

Making a component like "AuthProviderWithNavigate" is a good practice and using "Auth0Provider" as a children wrapper.
You can use this snippet code:

```
import { Auth0Provider, AppState } from '@auth0/auth0-react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

interface AuthProviderWithNavigateProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const AuthProviderWithNavigate: React.FC<AuthProviderWithNavigateProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const domain = process.env...... as string
  const clientId = process.env....... as string

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState?: AppState) => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname)
  }

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      }}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}>
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthProviderWithNavigate
```

Then wrap your **App** with **AuthProviderWithNavigate**.